# Google Flights flight cannot be found

Tags: tickets, online-resources

I've found an offer on Google Flights which I am not able to book somehow. 
It's a retour-trip from Amsterdam, Netherlands to San Jose, Costa Rica and Google FLights doesn't has a link to book the tickt. (Direct link to the Google Flight result: http://goo.gl/flights/psHc)

I've already tried to call with Swiss to book the flight, but they tell me they cannot find it either. Also ITA Matrix doesn't show this exact trip. Is this a bug in Google Flights or do I just have to look harder in order to get this ticket? And if so; where do I start looking? I already tried several other booking sites.

Answer (score 4):

If the flight is with Swissair and you can't book it with Swissair, you can assume there is no flight. Or does Swissair have the flight, but not at the price advertised?

The flight and price quite possibly existed at some point. This is implied by the same flight on dates in April, May and June being available at as little as 513 USD, now, as well as them being bookable through United.

Here's an example link (which will probably expire):

[United Airlines](http://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/booking/flight/reviewRevenue.aspx?SID=D92747130DA6429FB452785306A4B4B3&POS=NL&MobileOff=1)

Hipmunk lists the flight you searched for at about 1000 USD:

[Hipmunk.com](https://www.hipmunk.com/flights#f=AMS+-+Amsterdam+Airport+Schiphol+-+Amsterdam,+Netherlands;t=San+Jose,+Costa+Rica;d=2015-07-19;r=2015-08-01)

Momondo offers that flight for about 860 euros:

[Momondo.com](http://www.momondo.com/flightsearch/?Search=true&TripType=2&SegNo=2&SO0=AMS&SD0=SJO&SDP0=19-07-2015&SO1=SJO&SD1=AMS&SDP1=01-08-2015&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=false#Search=true&TripType=2&SegNo=2&SO0=AMS&SD0=SJO&SDP0=19-07-2015&SO1=SJO&SD1=AMS&SDP1=01-08-2015&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=false)

So, you likely found old flight data.

Comment: Thanks for the info and additional links. Do you have any idea how long such a flight and price can be found on Google Flights after its already gone? When I look for it I can still find it. How does Google get this data?

Comment: Good questions, but I don't have an answer for the first. I do think you're basically seeing a glitch. If I do a search for Amsterdam to San Jose on Google Flights and use the calendar view, I now get a lowest price for your dates of 902 USD, which is confirmed when I actually check on the specific dates. Though, this price is still not bookable online. I think Google directly taps into, what's it called, Amadeus? That is, the same system a travel agent would use.

Comment: Google Flights caches aggressively for speed. The flip side is that every now and then the cache is out of date.